# Authenticating users via Active Directory programmatically on REST service API call

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, active-directory

I have a spring mvc web app that has an API, that looks like this

`/api/createUser?name=Tom`.

At the same time there is a web site backed by the same web app, that has restricted pages, which can only be accessed once the a user authorizes using login form + Active Directory. I have managed to set up AD and it works well, but I am kinda lost with the API.

I want to make an authentication for API calls too. Namely, I want to introduce `username` and  `password` fields to every API call, so that when the relevant controller receives this API call, it first authenticates the user programmatically and it succeeded, then proceeds further with the request.

So the question is, how can I authenticate a user programmatically outright from MVC controller in Spring? Is there any magic bean that I can inject and harness its power?

Comment: Why not use spring security filter to secure the API calls as well? You can make it read auth info from query parameters.

Comment: yes, I can read auth info from query, but what should I do next with that? Is there some sort of authentication bean that I can autowire into the filter class and use e.g. `auth.checkCredentials(usern, pass)`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use spring sercurity

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/api**" access="ROLE_USER" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider>
    <user-service>
    <user name="username" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
    </user-service>
  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: I _am_ using spring security, namely ActiveDirectory authentication provider. However, I cannot get how the client could deliver username and password in every request (probably in request header?)